Is it possible to create a parameter-style dynamic multi slicer in Deneb for Power BI?
I am trying to create a scenario analysis report where I have multiple projects in my data set. Each project has its own Start and End dates. I want to be able to create something along the lines of 'What If' parameters for individually adjusting the Start date (by 'n' number of months) , but rather than create a parameter each for every project, I was wondering if this is something that can be done via Deneb.
I am not sure if we can 'pull' user selected values from a Deneb visual to be used in DAX measures outside of the visual itself. But if it works, the use case is as follows.... I have a table with unique project names. Lets say Project A, Project B and Project C. I want to be able to create a Multi  slider , which would list all 3 projects with a slider each.
When I add more projects in the future the visual should scale and create sliders accordingly.
I am new to Vega, so I had a run via Chat GPT, but failed miserably....
But the expected output is as follows:
The sliders should have a range of possible selections between -3 and +3 (representing 3 months forwards and 3 months backwards; default value as 0).
So the visual will have 3 sliders....
sample output
Even if we set up such a visual / multi slider, can we then pull the selected value against each slider into DAX?
